# Blurry text after using CSS transform: scale(); in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, css, webkit, transform, css-animations

Seems like there has been a recent update to Google Chrome that causes blurry text after doing a `transform: scale()`. Specifically I'm doing this:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes bounceIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(.3);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
  }

  70% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(.9);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

If you visit http://rourkery.com in Chrome, you should see the problem on the main text area. It didn't used to do this and it doesn't seem to effect other webkit browsers (like Safari). There were some other posts about people experiencing a similar issue with 3d transforms, but can't find anything about 2d transforms like this.

Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Just visited the site using Firefox and IE 10, don't see the problem. If it's limited to Chrome, you might need to wait for Google to fix it themselves.

Comment: I've come across this problem earlier too, as Nolonar mentioned we'll have to wait for Google to fix it.

Comment: Not a solution, but I have noticed that the issue only occurs for me when I use CSS optimizeLegibility.

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/antialiasing-101/ Anyone who suffers from blurry text should read this old article by Paul Lewis. In short it's mainly all about Subpixel antialiasing quirks.

Answer (score 121):

I have had this problem a number of times and there seems to be 2 ways of fixing it (shown below). You can use either of these properties to fix the rendering, or both at the same time.

Backface visibility hidden fixes the problem as it simplifies the animation to just the front of the object, whereas the default state is the front and the back.

```
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

TranslateZ also works as it is a hack to add hardware acceleration to the animation.

```
transform: translateZ(0);
```

Both of these properties fix the problem that you are having but some people also like to add

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
```

to their animated object. I find that it can change the rendering of a web font but feel free to experiment with that method too.

Comment: These techniques all seem to improve things, but I still can't get Chrome to the same level of clarity that I see in Firefox.

Comment: `backface-visibility: hidden;` sure worked in my case, in solving some weird blurry movement cause by opacity transition, that is. The weird movement is now gone, BUT it has made the texts in my div permanently blurred instead.

Comment: As @ykadaru suggested, try adding `perspective(1px)` to your `transform:` code, this worked for me in Chrome while nothing else solved the problem

Comment: Does not work on Chrome Version 65.0.3325.162 (Official Build) (64-bit)
running in Ubuntu 17.10 with Gnome X11 session (Wayland off)

Comment: In Chrome 72 the first two options cause the text to be blurry during & at the end of the transform

Comment: IN my case  backface-visibility: visible; helped to save the blurred text :)

Comment: I've been experiencing other bugs (like partially changed opacity for rgba values) caused by `scale()` and `backface-visibility: hidden;` fixed them--blurry text isn't the only weird thing that happens. I have only experienced these bugs in Chromium browsers.

Comment: I'm using a transition with opacity and scale on a parent element. During the transition the text was blurry and when finished it jumped  a few pixels. By adding `backface-visibility: hidden;` on the element that jumped, it was solved. Used chrome  77.0.3865.90 on Windows.

Comment: For future developers, please tread carefully using any of these. My web app's FPS dropped from +60 to under 38 the moment I enabled this thing. (I have tons of text over many scrollable elements). Basically, your animations are gonna look very sluggish, so unless your web app is running natively with its own chromium rendering engine without browser, don't use it most of the time; might not be worth it. Maybe try looking into changing the colors of your text or background or some other design choices that might have caused the issue in the first place. Make it a last resort.

Answer (score 58):

After trying everything else here with no luck, what finally fixed this issue for me was **removing** the `will-change: transform;` property. For some reason it caused horribly blurry looking scaling in Chrome, but not Firefox.

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this? I don't get it... :( This is a completely valid issue in some versions of chrome, and it seems "will-change" in general is still pretty new and probably shouldn't be used. For more info see https://greensock.com/will-change

Comment: Had the same issue. Thanks for posting.

Comment: I had the same issue with material-design-components rendering on Chrome 75.  Removing the "will-changed" css style fixed it.

Comment: Confirmed in Chrome 79

Comment: I have the opposite, adding `will-change: transform;` slightly fixes the issue

Comment: Worked for me on Chrome 80, unlike other fixes. Now it's only blurry during the transition animation, which is a different issue, I guess. Thanks!

Comment: This fixed it for me on Chrome 86

Comment: This is very odd. As the workarounds in the solution doesn't work for my simple keyframe animation, this actually resolved the blurry result.

```
@keyframes heart-pulse {
    from {
      transform: scale(0);
      opacity: 1;
    }
    25% {
      transform: scale(1.15);
    }
    50% {
      transform: scale(1);
    }
    75% {
      transform: scale(1.15);
    }
    to {
      transform: scale(1);
      opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me! However, it led to major performance reductions when lots of content was in the scroll-view. I eventually found a solution using the following answer (on another question), which works nicely for this as well (triggers a re-rasterization by briefly setting `display = "none"` then resetting to `display = ""`): https://stackoverflow.com/a/41426352

Answer (score 33):

To improve the blurriness, esp. on Chrome, try doing this:

```
transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

[Perspective](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective) adds distance between the user and the z-plane, which technically scales the object, making the blurriness seem 'permanent'. The `perspective(1px)` above is like *duck-tape* because we're matching the blurriness we're trying to solve. You might have better luck with the css below:

```
transform: translateZ(0);
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Comment: For me, this actually makes it worse.

Comment: For me this fixes the glitch (without this, the element moves 1px after animation is done, transform: perspective(1px) alone fix this!)

Comment: @balu check my updated answer! get rid of the `perspective(1px)` property and see if it works better.

Comment: You answered with exactly the same question code.

Answer (score 24):

I found that adjusting the scale ratio helped slightly.

Using `scale(1.048)` over `(1.05)` seemed to generate a better approximation to a whole-pixel font size, reducing the sub-pixel blurring.

I also used `translateZ(0)` which seems to adjust Chrome's final rounding step in the transform animation. This is a plus for my onhover usage because it increases speed and reduces visual noise. For an onclick function however, I wouldn't use it because, the transformed font doesn't appear to be as crispy.

Comment: That's the only approach that worked for me. The other approaches (backface-visibility, adding filters, perspective and good old translateZ) just made it worse. Try scaling to whole pixels. For example go from 14px to 16px using a scale factor of 1,1429 (16/14).

Comment: Worked for me without `translateZ(0)`,  changed just `1.05` to `1.048`

Answer (score 19):

Instead of

```
transform: scale(1.5);
```

using

```
zoom : 150%;
```

fixes the text blurring problem in Chrome.

Comment: It can help but also introduces other issues, like white border lines being introduced sometimes

Comment: Exactly.  But I found no other method that could remove text-blur problem in Chrome.  So, I've been using zoom for my website.  Can't understand the downvotes though!

Comment: not sure why the downvote. When I applied this to checkboxes this worked much better than transform: scale()

Comment: For firefox, use transform: scale() works like charm without any blurriness. You'll have to work on browser detection and act accordingly for chrome/safari and firefox.

Comment: Another issue is that zoom doesn't seem to work with the transition property, so it can't be used for CSS animations

Comment: It works and fox the blur thing, but it also changes position of elements.

Comment: @user1156544 : yes it does, that would anyway be happening even when you're doing `transform: scale({scaleVal});`, you will need to position your elements `left`/`top` accordingly which is an easy calculation based on `{scaleVal}`

Comment: Not supported by any version of FF! So you probably don't want to use it.

Comment: This is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Comment: It is not advisable to use `zoom` property just yet. According to MDN, it is a Non-standard CSS property. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom

Answer (score 13):

This must be a bug with Chrome (Version 56.0.2924.87), but the below fixes the bluriness for me when changing css properties in the console('.0'). I'll report it.

```
filter: blur(.0px)
```

Comment: Did you get anywhere with your bug report?

Comment: afraid I don't even recall where I submitted the bug to. Did so though.

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap (4.4.1), Chrome (80.0.3987.132), Windows 10 (with view 125% scaled up) and I have blurry texts in dropdown menu. The menu is positioned using `transform: translate3d();` and this seems to cause the problem. None of the suggested solutions worked for me. Except/kinda this one. This works only if I set it first to some positive value (e.g., `blur(0.1px)`) and then change to `blur(0px)`. Since the element is dynamic, and also requires a dynamic (JS) solution, ... this sucks :\

Answer (score 8):

Sunderls lead me to the answer. Except `filter: scale` does not exist, but `filter: blur` does.

Apply the next declarations to the elements that appear blurred (in my case they were inside a transformed element):

```
backface-visibility: hidden;    
-webkit-filter: blur(0);
```

It *almost* worked perfectly. "*Almost*" because i'm using a transition and while in transition, elements don't look perfect, but once the transition is done, they do.

Comment: `-webkit-filter: blur(0);` alone works for me. `backface-visibility: hidden;` blurs my element when I reset the scaling afterwards.

Comment: this is kinda funny for Chrome... if i set `blur(0px);` it doesnt fix it. but if i do `blur(1px);` and then press the arrow down key to `blur(0px);` it does look correct. Gone on page refresh / no matter what I write in the CSS

Comment: @TomRoggero This sounds less specific to the blur property value and more about when redraw of the layout is done. You could experiment forcing redraw of the element using JavaScript after some delay.

Comment: -webkit-filter: blur(0);  transform: perspective(1px) translateY(0) translateZ(0); those fixed my problem

Answer (score 8):

I have found a much better and clean solution:

```
.element{
 transform:scale(0.5) 
 transform-origin: 100% 0;
}
```

or

```
.element{
 transform:scale(0.5) 
 transform-origin: 0% 0;
}
```

Thanks to this post:
[Preventing blurry rendering with transform: scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037176/preventing-blurry-rendering-with-transform-scale/29037803)

Comment: This 'solved' the problem in Firefox 85 on Windows and improved, but not completely solved in Chrome 88...

Also, sadly, you can't really use it freely.

Answer (score 7):

In my case following code caused blurry font:

```
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
```

and just adding zoom property fixed it for me. Play around with zoom, following worked for me:

```
zoom: 97%;
```

Comment: No firefox support for `zoom`

Answer (score 7):

I found out, that the problem occures on relative transforms in any way. translateX(50%), scale(1.1) or what ever. providing absolute values always works (does not produce blurry text(ures)).

None of the solutions mentions here worked, and I think there is not solution, yet (using Chrome 62.0.3202.94 while I am writing this).

In my case `transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%)` causes the blur (I want to center a dialog).

To reach a bit more "absolute" values, I had to set decimal values to `transform: translateY(-50.09%) translateX(-50.09%)`.

**NOTE**

I am quite sure, that this values vary on different screen sizes. I just wanted to share my experiences, in case it helps someone.

Comment: I was running in to this exact same issue doing the exact same thing. I was centering a modal with translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0). In my case, I bumped up the values to -50.048% and it looks perfect.

Answer (score 5):

**2019 Update**
The Chrome display bug is still unfixed and though no fault of the patrons, none of the suggestions offered in the entirety of this website help to resolve the issue. I can concur that I have tried every single one of them in vain: only 1 comes close and that's the css rule: filter:blur(0); which eliminates the shifting of a container by 1px but does not resolve the blurred display bug of the container itself and any content it may have.

**Here's the reality: there literally is no fix to this problem so here is a work around for fluid websites**

**CASE**
I'm currently developing a fluid website and have 3 divs, all centered with hover effects and sharing percentage values in both the width and position. The Chrome bug occurs on the center container which is set to left:50%; and transform:translateX(-50%); a common setting.

**EXAMPLE:** First the HTML...

```
<div id="box1" class="box">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry"s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
</div>

<div id="box2" class="box">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry"s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
</div>

<div id="box3" class="box">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry"s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
</div>
```

**Here's the CSS where the Chrome bug occurs...**

```
*{margin:0; padding:0; border:0; outline:0; box-sizing:border-box;  background:#505050;}
.box {position:absolute; border:1px solid #fff; border-radius:10px; width:26%; background:#8e1515; padding:25px; top:20px; font-size:12pt; color:#fff; overflow:hidden; text-align:center; transition:0.5s ease-in-out;}
.box:hover {background:#191616;}
.box:active {background:#191616;}
.box:focus {background:#191616;}
#box1 {left:5%;}
#box2 {left:50%; transform:translateX(-50%);} /* Bugged */
#box3 {right:5%;}
```

**Here's the fixed css...**

```
*{margin:0; padding:0; border:0; outline:0; box-sizing:border-box;  background:#505050;}
.box {position:absolute; border:1px solid #fff; border-radius:10px; width:26%; background:#8e1515; padding:25px; top:20px; font-size:12pt; color:#fff; overflow:hidden; text-align:center; transition:0.5s ease-in-out;}
.box:hover {background:#191616;}
.box:active {background:#191616;}
.box:focus {background:#191616;}
#box1 {left:5%;}
#box2 {left:37%;} /* Fixed */
#box3 {right:5%;}
```

**Bugged fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/m9bgrunx/2/
**Fixed fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/uoc6e2dm/2/

As you can see a small amount of tweaking to the CSS should reduce or eliminate the requirement to use transform for positioning. This could also apply to fixed width websites as well as fluid.

Comment: Blurriness is expected when using translation, because the element can end up on a [half pixel](https://martinkool.com/post/27618832225/beware-of-half-pixels-in-css). There are now better alternatives for centering things: [flexbox sample](https://jsfiddle.net/timothy003/td4jeLxz/), [grid sample](https://jsfiddle.net/timothy003/x47j1hu2/)

Comment: The only browser I've tested which seems to have an issue with transform center is Chrome, everything else appears crystal clear. I looked back and this issue has been around for 7 years! Still there's plenty of ways to skin a cat and like you say it's not even required anymore.

Comment: this is unbelievable, but filter: blur (-0.1px); helped me !!. how the hell does this work ??

Comment: @jt3k You're forcing Chrome to render in software, which rounds to the nearest pixel. In short: don't do that.

Answer (score 5):

I have this same problem. I fixed this using:

```css
.element {
  display: table
}
```

Comment: insane but it works; Chrome is the new IE apparently

Comment: oooow lord! ir works! i guess table 'fix' de width in PX did not possible width with half-pixel...

Answer (score 4):

Another fix to try i just found for blurry transforms (translate3d, scaleX) on Chrome is to set the element as 
"**display: inline-table**;". 
It seems to force pixel rounding in some case (on the X axis).

I read subpixel positioning under Chrome was intended and devs won't fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `zoom: 101%;` for complex designs when you can't use a combination of zoom + scale.

Comment: Note that `zoom` is not defined by any web standard and is not supported by firefox https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-zoom

Answer (score 2):

It's important to add that this issue arises if the element which is being translated has a height with an odd number of pixels. So, if you have control over the height of the element, setting it to an even number will make the content appear crisp

Comment: I used even numbered dimensions, and the element is still blurry.

Comment: This simply doesn't add anything to this post.

Comment: Using even numbers didn't help with the bluriness of the animation BUT it helped with my subpixel positionning, which was another problem I had when positionning items in an infinite scroll. Thanks for the tip !

Answer (score 2):

None of above worked for me.
I had this animation for popups:

```
@keyframes pulse {
  from {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}
```

In my case blurry effect was gone after applying this rule:
`-webkit-perspective: 1000;` even though it is marked as unused in Chrome inspector.

Comment: It works for me and it is also marked as unused. I have also added `will-change: transform;` that fixes blurry of elements borders. Any other answers didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

None of the above worked for me.

It worked when I added perspective

ie from

`transform : translate3d(-10px,-20px,0) scale3d(0.7,0.7, 1)`

i changed to

`transform : perspective(1px) translate3d(-10px,-20px,0) scale3d(0.7,0.7, 1)`

Comment: Adding `perspective(1px)` actually made it worse for me :(

Answer (score 2):

I used a combination of all answers and this is what worked for me in the end:

```
.modal .modal--transition {
  display: inline-table;
  transform: perspective(1px) scale(1) translateZ(0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution was:

display: initial;

Then it was crispy sharp

Comment: Note that this won't work on `span` or any other inline elements.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the blurry text issue on Chrome but not on Firefox when I used `transform: translate(-50%,-50%)`.

Well, I really tried a lot of workarounds like:

```css
transform: perspective(1px);
```

```css
filter: blur(0);
```

```css
transform: translateZ(0);
```

```css
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

None of these worked to me.

Finally, I made the height and width of the element even. It resolved the issue for me!!!

**Note:** It might depend from use case to use case. But surely worth a try!

Comment: Yes, using width:0 and height:0, and animating with transition : width .15s, height.15s (instead of transform:scale(0) and transition:transform .15s) does the job, but you lose the transform origin (may be I can hack this by animating margin), and it is a little bit janky (I can see 2-3 intermediate frames)

Comment: You should use ```backface-visibility: hidden;``` AND ```transform: translateZ(0);``` . Z transform tells the engine to use 3D rendering. Until that, ```backface-visibility``` has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried a lot of examples from these answers unfortunately nothing help for 
Chrome `Version 81.0.4044.138`
I have added to transforming element instead

```
 transform-origin: 50% 50%;
```

this one

```
 transform-origin: 51% 51%;
```

it helps for me

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me:

`body { perspective: 1px; }`

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my case by adding:

```
transform: perspective(-1px)
```

Comment: This for me just removed the `scale()` transform result

Answer (score 1):

I removed this from my code -  `transform-style: preserve-3d;`
and added this- `transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);`

the blur went away!

Answer (score 1):

FOR CHORME:

I´ve tried all suggestions here. But diden't work.
My college found a great solution, that works better:

**You should NOT scale past 1.0**

And include `translateZ(0)` in the hover but NOT in the none-hover/initial position.

Example:

```
a {
    transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000);
    transform: scale(0.8, 0.8);
}

a:hover {
    transform: translateZ(0)scale(1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Now for me it starts blurry and goes to clear.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome 74.0.3729.169, current as of 5-25-19, there doesn't seem to be any fix for blurring occurring at certain browser zoom levels caused by the transform. Even a simple `TransformY(50px)` will blur the element. This doesn't occur in current versions of Firefox, Edge or Safari, and it doesn't seem to occur at all zoom levels.

Comment: This is what happened to my. I can't get rid of this blur effect. One solution which have worked is to set these properties: `top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0; right: 0; margin: auto` but then the container will take the whole space it can (it must be width), so this doesn't work in case when the content should decide how big container will be.

Answer (score 1):

So. I tried all the solutions above and nothing really worked. But!

I have a modal-root div in my index.html of my React App. I am rendering a Modal component (.modal) in it if it is necessary. First I positioned the modal itself fixed, making it top-left 50% and applied a transition(-50%, -50%) to get it centered.

I zoomed in-and-out and noticed the blurriness of the modal content if the zoom ratio of the Chrome browser was not 100%. It could be 110% or 90-80-75 etc. percent, doesn't matter. Apart from 100% zoom it was really blurry and ugly.

So I decided to get rid of the entire transition-based solution that I had before to center the child of the .modal element.

I am positioning my modal-root fixed, making it top-left-right-bottom 0, so it is always 100vh and wv. Then I made it a flex-container and positioned its child via align-items and justify-content centered.

But! There is always a but. The modal-root has a z-index: -1 on default. I decided to change it programmatically to 59 if the modal is opened. I also apply an overlay that makes the rest of the page darker, that is the .overlay which has a z-index of 60. The actual modal content (.modal) has a z-index of 61.

I also wanted to animate the entrance of that element when it appears so I am playing around with the margins, instead of applying any kind of transition to it. It's a cubic-bazier animation that handles that margin-top at the fitting percent within the animation but at the end it is margin-top 0 with no transition property.

It was a bit pity to have to rework the component but after testing it it works pretty fine.

Summary:

- Highest parent container fixed, covering the entire page
- Setting the highest parentcontainer's z-index -1 or [custom-value] depending on wanting to interacting with the modal (modal is open)
- Setting the container's z-index to -1 if the modal is closed
- Making the container a flex-container and position its child to the center
- Animating the child via margin values instead of transition

I hope it can be helpful for some of you folks :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a div that has a small perspective shift on it to give a subtle 3D effect. The text in the div was blurring and I tried all the suggestions here to no avail.

Oddly, I found that setting 'filter: inherit;' on the text elements vastly improved the clarity. Though I can't understand why.

Here's my code in case it helps:

Html:

```
<div id="NavContainer">
    <div id="Nav">
        <label>Title</label>
        <nav>
            <a href="/">home</a>
            <a href="/link1">link1</a>
            <a href="/link2">link2</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
    #NavContainer {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 20px;
        right: 20px;
        perspective: 80vw;
        perspective-origin: top center;
    }

    #Nav {
        text-align: right;
        transform: rotateX(-5deg);
    }

        #Nav > nav > a,
        #Nav > label {
            display: inline-block;
            filter: inherit;
        }

        #Nav > label {
            float: left;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that my elements were using `transformStyle: preserve-3d`. I realized that this wasn't actually needed for the app and removing it fixed the blurriness.

Answer (score 0):

It will be difficult to solve with only css.

So I solved it with jquery.

This is my CSS.

```
.trY {
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.trX {
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.trXY {
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

and this is my jquery.

```
function tr_init() {
$(".trY, .trX, .trXY").each(function () {
    if ($(this).outerWidth() % 2 != 0) {
        var fixed_width = Math.ceil($(this).outerWidth() / 2) * 2;
        $(this).css("width", fixed_width);
    }
    if ($(this).outerHeight() % 2 != 0) {
        var fixed_height = Math.ceil($(this).outerHeight() / 2) * 2;
        $(this).css("height", fixed_height);
    }
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the fix craze, putting {border:1px solid #???} around the badly looking object fixes the issue for me.
In case you have a stable background colour, consider this too.
This is so dumb noone thought about mentioning I guess, eh eh.

Comment: This did not make a difference for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the mistake was that the animation was set to a parent div of the animated element (an SVG). The parent div had some crazy width, like 466.667px. Setting that to an odd number wouldn't help. But: targetting the SVG itself with the animation (instead of the parent container did).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading in the future:
In my case the issue was that I added:

```
perspective: 2500px;
```

To a parent element. Removing this property resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with zoom value on the animated block.
In my case, zoom: 99.6%; totally fixes the blurry text. But for example, with 99.7% value text is still blurry, so in each case this value can vary.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to remove `backdrop-filter: blur(8px);`. While this filter was only being applied to the background of a `<div>`, and not to its text, it seems like merely the presence of this property causes Chrome to slightly blur the text when used with `transform: scale();`.

Answer (score 0):

I was using box-shadow on my card and that is why it was causing me trouble after removing that box-shadow i was able to see crisp text after scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this rule seperately to transformed element.
both are working:

```
border:0 !important;
or 
border-radius:0 !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, my solution had a bit of luck involved. My solution only works in certain scenarios. My browser is chrome 120.0.6099.110.
I solved this problem by adding

```
content-visable:auto
```

to the text wrapping layer. I have tried all the above-mentioned upvoted answers, but to no avail.
My interface is a table. For product comparison, the transform:scaleY(-1) element needs to be flipped and reduced in the vertical direction, that is, upside down. When there are more than 8 products compared, the DOM content of the page will be very large, with many columns and rows of data, then there will be problems with Chrome rendering, and the problem of blurred fonts will occur.
By adding content-visable:auto, the browser will reduce some rendering content, this is my understanding. I have a horizontal scroll bar to drag and display all the content, because one screen cannot display everything. No problem dragging, great content-viable

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

highest rated solution works but not for <h1...6> tags, had to specify font-size for them to work.

Answer (score -2):

you can use css `filter` to fix this.

```
.element {
    filter: blur(0);
}
```

about vendor-prefix, please do it by yourself.`-webkit-filter`,`-ms-filter`.
detail is here
http://browser.colla.me/show/css_transformation_scale_cause_blurring

Comment: There is no `filter: scale` according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter

Comment: It should be blur according to the referenced URL in the answer.