# Repainting slowdown only occurs when child not transformed

Tags: ios, css, google-chrome, repaint

I've got a parent (map) with many children (pins). When panning the map, I'm getting a lot of slowdown due to repainting. It is fixed, however, as soon as a child's pin is tapped and the thumbnail within the pin is transformed. What is going on? Is there a way to cache the whole parent so it repaints as little as possible?

[image: Repainting Visualization]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a `filter: blur(0)` statement on the map container. I read it could reduce blur on CSS transform scaling, but apparently it just slowed everything down.

Saw the blur comment here, but removing it solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34209098/840982