# Using transform scale causes blurry text only on Windows Chrome

Tags: css, transform, scale

I have run into a pretty frustrating problem regarding the CSS transform `scale`. I have a block of text which I would like to zoom by 105% on hover and it is causing blurriness of the text, but only on the Windows version of Chrome. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677490/blurry-text-after-using-css-transform-scale-in-chrome) and tried the various solutions provided there, but I still cannot get it to work as desired.

```css
body, html {
  font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.zoom {
  transition:transform .5s;
  width:300px;
  margin:50px auto;
}
  .zoom:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05) translateZ(0);
    will-change:transform;
  }
  .zoom h4 {
    font-size:2rem;
    line-height:2.5rem;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-filter: blur(0);
    filter: blur(0);
    margin:0;
    text-transform:uppercase;
  }
  .zoom p {
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    -webkit-filter:blur(0);
    filter:blur(0);
    margin:0;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="zoom">                  
  <h4>Lorem Ipsum</h4>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conse ctetur adipiscing elit…</p>
</div>
```

As I mentioned earlier, this only seems to be an issue on the Windows version of Chrome. On Chrome for OSX, FireFox and even IE this issue does not occur. I am open to using a different solution than `transform`, provided the animation has a transition as it does in my example. I would, however, like for it to be a CSS only solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I can't test it myself right now as I don't have a Windows computer handy, but maybe you can do either solutions:

1. Adding `backface-visibility: hidden;` to `.zoom`
2. Changing your `transform` on `.zoom:hover` property to `transform: scale(1.05) translateZ(0);`

This *should* trigger GPU material acceleration and just *might* solve your issue on Chrome. No promises, though. Good luck!

Comment: I had already tried the `backface-visibility` solution based on the other question I found, but it does not resolve the issue. I updated my question to include `translateZ(0);` in the transform as you suggested, but the issue persists. Thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: Another idea might be to add the `will-change: transform;` property to`.zoom` but I'm pulling at straws at this point, haha.

Comment: Wow... will-change actually did it for me, thanks @chriskirknielsen!

Comment: same issue on Linux Chrome; setting `will-change` helped