# Text blurs when using transition and scale Chrome and FireFox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

when I use both `transition` and`transform`, then the animations are not very smooth on both `chrome` and`firefox`. It *blurs* when you hover over it. The only browser on which it is normal is `IE`.

**Chome / FireFox** (Note the text, when the animation starts it start to be blurry. When it finishes it pops back to smooth letters.)
[image]

**Desired result** (This is working in IE)
[image]

How do I make these *animations* also smooth on `chrome` and `firefox`?

**Snippet:**

as soon as the transition is complete, the element has to be focused again. Thats what it looks like now on `chrome` and `firefox`.

```css
button {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  border: 1px solid cornflowerblue;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: all .33s ease-in-out;
}

button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: all .33s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<button>Hover me</button>
```

Comment: it seems smooth for me ? what is the exact issue ?

Comment: You use chrome or firefox?

Comment: Do you mean the blur part?

Comment: i use both of them

Comment: @TimGerhard Yes it starts blurring when you hover over it. In IE this doenst happen.

Comment: See added gifs.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677490/blurry-text-after-using-css-transform-scale-in-chrome#16878602

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/antialiasing-101/ Anyone who suffers from blurry text should read this old article by Paul Lewis. In short it's mainly all about Subpixel antialiasing quirks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can accomplish a very similar effect using font relative units (em) and increasing the element font-size on hover.

```
button {
  font-size: .875em; /* =14/16 or whatever your base font size is */
  padding: .625em; /* =10/16 */
  border-radius: .1875em; /* =3/16 */
}

button:hover {
  font-size: 1em; /* close enough to 1.1x */
}
```

Note this generally considered to be *less* performant than using transforms, at the very least try to position the element so that there are fewer re-flows around it.

Chrome 64 on Windows 10:

[image: Chrome Windows]

```css
button {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  border: 1px solid cornflowerblue;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: .875em; /* =14/16 or whatever your base font size is */
  color: #fff;
  padding: .625em; /* =10/16 */
  border-radius: .1875em; /* =3/16 */
  transition: all .33s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

button:hover {
  font-size: 1em; /* close enough to 1.1x */
  transition: all .33s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<span style="position: relative; left: 2.5em; top: 1em;">
  <button>Hover me</button>
</span>
```

Comment: Although the blur is indeed gone, the button starts growing from the top left. How can I make it grow from the center? Because this looks wierd in the design.

Comment: @Red negative margins or `transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);` would do the trick; keep in mind you'll have to offset the transform

Comment: Thanks @o.v. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to remove the blur on Firefox with:

Backface visibility hidden fixes the problem as it simplifies the animation to just the front of the object, whereas the default state is the front and the back.

```
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

or ( *or both* )

TranslateZ also works as it is a hack to add hardware acceleration to the animation.

```
transform: translateZ(0);
```

Comment: Don't just copy-past [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677490/blurry-text-after-using-css-transform-scale-in-chrome#16878602)

Comment: When using this its still kinda blurry on chrome.

Answer (score 2):

You can try if perspective can fix your issue, it fixes the text into it's z-axis, no technical idea why.

```css
button {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  border: 1px solid cornflowerblue;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: all .33s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-perspective: 1;
  perspective: 1;
}

button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: all .33s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<button>Hover me</button>
```

Comment: I dont see any improvement in your fiddle. It still makes the letters blur.

Answer (score -1):

The best and so far only way I found which removes the blur effect is to scale down the element first, and then scaling it up to its original size.
Here's an example:

```css
button {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  border: 1px solid cornflowerblue;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: all .33s ease-in-out;
  transform:scale(0.7);
}

button:hover {
  transform : perspective(1px) scale(1);
  transition: all .33s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<button>Hover me</button>
```

I know this is not the desired result but I looked quite hard and didn't find anything better.

Comment: The text still blurs when the animation start.

Comment: I'm aware of that but its way less blury than any other solution provided so far

Comment: Hm, not on my desktop? Its still the same, only the animation makes the button much bigger then the questions fiddle.

Comment: I think it only tricks your eyes. Because the letters are smaller and the button bigger. Its not what I want though. The button must stay the way its in the questions fiddle, I only wanna get ride of the annoying blur effect. It makes the animation so uggly :|

Comment: I think you gotta live with that until chrome patches it. You could use an image though!

Comment: Yes perhaps, maybe a chrome dev will read and patch it. Who knows ;)