# CSS Scaling text makes it blurry, how can I make it look normal?

Tags: css, css-transitions, scale

I have this element that on click has a scale animation, while the animation is taking place, the text becomes too blurry, and then returns to it´s normal appereance, it looks like the font-size changes, but that is not happening, it is the extreme blurryness that is added to the text while scaling.

[image: animated gif shows the problem]

Check at the end of the transition how the text "loses" the blurryness.. it really **looks bad**.

I have tried adding these CSS properties:

```
backface-visibility: hidden;
transform: translateZ(0);
```

to the div that contains the text (.content) but it makes things worse on Chrome...can´t seem to remove the blurryness.

Is there anything that can fix this via CSS? Or should I try a Javascript solution?

looks bad

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge this is a known issue in Chrome and has to do with rounding issues in floats. If you execute any `transform` on elements that have well-defined edges, and their edges are `transformed` to `uneven pixel offsets`, this is the result. The only solution is to make sure the positioning is always rounded.

This issue can also be reproduced by using a google font inside a `div` with the properties `position: absolute; top: 50%, left: 50%, transform(-50%, -50%);`

For further reference you can also check this related post:
[Blurry text after using CSS transform: scale(); in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677490/blurry-text-after-using-css-transform-scale-in-chrome)