# Blurry content on css animation on Chrome

Tags: css, css-animations, tachyons-css

Here are the css properties for the `.grow` class in Tachyons CSS.

```
.grow {
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
}
```

It seems to follow the best practices for properly zooming on hover.

The zooming animation looks fine in firefox and Safari, but will look horribly blurry on chrome.

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blurry text after using CSS transform: scale(); in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677490/blurry-text-after-using-css-transform-scale-in-chrome)

Comment: The recommendations proposed in the answers are already included in the Tachyons class I'm using.