# Blurry font after applying transform

Tags: html, css, transform, chromium, blurry

I am trying to achieve an animation akin to door/folder opening by applying `rotateY` to a div that contains texts and images. When applied, text elements become blurry:
[blurry_chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx5Z8.png)

All that is applied to the divs are this:

```css
.folder:hover {
  transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.12);
}

.folder:hover .front-cover {
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(-20.44deg);
}
```

The problem persists even when one or the other is stripped away. Text is still blurry when only `scale` or `rotateY` is applied.
On firefox, the issue seems to actually be far worse:
[blurry_firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqWBz.png)

I have tried quite a few hacks like `translateZ(0)`, `blur(0)` and `font-smoothing` and it hasn't changed anything.

Is there no way to work around this if I want this effect?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/mello-code/pen/XWpzxWd

Edit:
Some of the 'solutions' I have already tried:

- -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
- filter: blur(0);
- transform-origin: 51% 51%;
- making div sizes, elements, paddings and margins even
- backface-visibility: hidden;
- perspective(1px) (There is already perspective applied on hover)
- zoom instead of scale

None of them seem to help. Any ideas?

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677490/blurry-text-after-using-css-transform-scale-in-chrome

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blurry text after using CSS transform: scale(); in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677490/blurry-text-after-using-css-transform-scale-in-chrome)

Comment: Unfortunately no, I have tried a lot of those and none of them seems to help.

Comment: Its blurring when you change the perspective with `transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(-20.44deg);`. You can try using a different degree, or not rotating it at all. You can also get less blurring if you scale it up to 1.5 instead of 1.2. Alternatively, you can scale it up by changing the width, height, font sizes instead of using scale.

Comment: @John Yes, I can leave out the scaling but removing the `rotateY` altogether kinda defeats the purpose of trying to resolve the issue in the first place. I've tried different angles, but they seem to be all more or less the same.

Comment: Its probably overkill, but you could try making the font as canvas elements instead. It won't be selectable, but would probably look better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scale` was the biggest culprit here. Scaling up over 1 causes blur, so rather than scaling up when hovered, I had the element scale down and up to 1 when hovered.

Additionally, removing `perspective` from transformation yielded crisp text and images.

Answer (score 0):

There is:
`-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased` which should give you the sharpest result, but it is not standardized.

See more about font smoothing here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth

This answer might be also helpful:

[Blurry text after using CSS transform: scale(); in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677490/blurry-text-after-using-css-transform-scale-in-chrome)

Comment: I have already tried this answer. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to change the result in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is other styles on the element or its parents.  In my case `border-radius` being applied to the same element, plus a translate, scale, and scroll bars combined to make the text blurry.  It is worse at some scales than others, and at different monitor resolutions.  This is fine in firefox and safari.

How it looks on a 1440p monitor:

[image]

https://codepen.io/culli/pen/poBzPGJ

https://issues.chromium.org/issues/41321934?pli=1