# CSS Blurry font & image after transform

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a 3D tilted frame. After creating it my fonts and my images are blurry for some reason. I tried to research the issue but no luck. Code is down bellow.

Note : When I zoom-out in edge , it's not anymore blurred , but then rotateY get highed deg.
[image]

```
.testL{
  transform: perspective(1500px) rotateY(15deg) ;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 25px 50px -12px;
  transition: transform 1s ease 0s;
}

.testR{
  transform: perspective(1500px) rotateY(-15deg);
  border-radius: 1rem;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 25px 50px -12px;
  transition: transform 1s ease 0s;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677490/blurry-text-after-using-css-transform-scale-in-chrome

Comment: Tried it already , no luck.

Comment: Have you checked out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464055/css-transition-effect-makes-image-blurry-moves-image-1px-in-chrome). Specifically the `image-rendering` answer.